# MsgBox when user tries to delete a row

Tags: vba, excel, rowdeleting

I am building a tool in excel and have protected the workbook so that deleting or inserting rows/columns is not allowed, using the code below:

```
Sub ProtectSheet()
ActiveSheet.Protect _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=True, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, _
    Password:=cPassword
End Sub
```

However, I also want a message box to appear if the user tries to delete or insert a row/column that tells them they cannot do this and provides other instructions. Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: how about using a `MsgBox` before your code runs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selection change event like this (code to go in the worksheet's code module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = .EntireRow.Address Or .Address = .EntireColumn.Address Then
            MsgBox "You can not insert or delete any row or column", vbInformation, "FYI"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If they try to insert or delete by selecting entire rows or columns (which is how I typically go about doing that) then this message box will pop up, but it won't pop up if you select smaller ranges of cells.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! That was exactly what I needed.